# How can I edit a CMAKELIST.txt file on CLION to take LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS

Tags: macos, cmake, openssl, clion

I installed openssl1.1.1d on MAC Mojave and I added the following on my .bash_profile:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
```

I have been trying to get this code to compile on CLION and I keep getting an error.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(untitled3 C)
SET (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT} $ENV{LDFLAGS})
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/openssl)
include_directories(${I})
link_libraries(ssl)
link_libraries(crypto)
set(SOURCE_FILES mywebsock.c)
add_executable(untitled3 mywebsock.c)
```

Error message:

```
fatal error: 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found
#include <openssl/ssl.h> 1 error generated.
```

I tried compiling on my terminal like this:

```
gcc -Wall -o mywebsock mywebsock.c -lssl -lcrypto -pthread
```

I got this error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OPENSSL_init_ssl", referenced from:
      _init_openssl in mywebsock -8aaca3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I think this is because I got the linking wrong. Please, can someone help me out? I have spent all night trying to figure this out. I have installed and reinstalled openssl. I have checked several posts but I cannot seem to get it right somehow.

Comment: In the line `set(/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/openssl)` - you seems to forgot to specify a **name** for the variable which you want to set.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cargo-culting stuff and getting lost in the process, just [load all those configuration settings from the pkg-config (.pc) file it installed for you](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html):

```
list(PREPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED) 
pkg_check_modules(Ssl IMPORTED_TARGET openssl)

add_executable(untitled3 mywebsock.c)
target_link_libraries(untitled3 PkgConfig::Ssl)
```

The `IMPORTED_TARGET` bit will create a target with all necessary settings for including OpenSSL.